# Como validar registro php y que no se repita

Tags: php, login, registro

Estoy intentando crear un sistema de registro de usuarios en php, y la idea es : Al insertar un correo no se repita, es decir que te obligue a que coloques un correo que aun no esta en la base de datos.

Aquí esta lo que tengo:
Es muy básico pero es para comenzar en esto, quisiera saber que colocar ya que he probando otras formas y simplemente me salta no lo consigo.

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';

if (isset($_POST['registro'])) {

    $usuario = $_POST['nombre_user'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena_user'];
    $correo = $_POST ['correo_user'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id_user, nombre_user, contrasena_user, correo_user) VALUES (null, '$usuario','$contrasena', '$correo')";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);


if($resultado){
   echo "<script> alert('bienvenid@ $usuario'); window.location='centro.html'</script>";
} else {

 
   echo "<script> alert('bienvenid@ $usuario'); window.location='registro.html'</script>";

   echo "No se puede insertar la informacion" . "<br>";
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conexion);
}

}
```

Comment: " simplemente me salta error" cuál?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el trabajo a medio hacer.

La idea principal antes de insertar un nuevo usuario es verificar que este no exista en los registros.

el codigo quedaria algo asi:

```
<?php
require 'conexion.php';



if (isset($_POST['registro'])) {

$usuario =  $_POST['nombre_user'];
$contrasena = $_POST['contrasena_user'];
$correo = $_POST['correo_user'];


$sql = "SELECT count(*) from usuarios where correo_user = '$correo'";
$verificar = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

if($verificar == 0){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id_user, nombre_user, contrasena_user, correo_user) VALUES (null, '$usuario','$contrasena', '$correo')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    if($resultado)    echo "<script> alert('bienvenid@ $usuario'); window.location='centro.html'</script>";
    else echo "<script> alert('bienvenid@ $usuario'); window.location='registro.html'</script>";
}else{
    else echo "<script> alert('Ya tienes una cuenta con el correo $correo'); window.location='registro.html'</script>"
}
```

Nota : no he probado el codigo, ya que no tengo accesso a `conexion.php`

Comment: La comprobación está mal. Tú estás verificando el resultado de la llamada a `mysqli_query`, o sea, si la consulta funcionó o no y no se trata de eso. Debes obtener el valor de la columna que arroja el `COUNT()`, para ello debes hacer `fetch`. Algo así: **`$row = mysqli_fetch_row($verificar);  if ($row[0] == 0) { //Insertar } else { //Existe }`**

Comment: Y, para otro tipo de código, deberías tener cuidado cuando haces comparaciones no estrictas. Por ejemplo esto: `if($verificar == 0){` entrará en el `if` **si la consulta falla**, porque en ese caso `mysqli_query()` devuelve `false`, y en una comparación no estricta `false` es igual a `0`. Para comparar no solamente los valores, sino también los tipos de datos, debes usar `===`. Para más detalles sobre esto revisa los [operadores de comparación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php) en el Manual de PHP.

Comment: Y no es más rápido hacer el insert previo haber dejado como **unique** la columna correo?? Si la query del insert devuelve error (puede incluso capturarse el error exacto) entonces le decimos al usuario que el email ya existe...

Comment: @OCHOA No necesariamente.  **Un `SELECT COUNT(*)`  será menos costoso que una situación de error, si la BD está bien diseñada**. Además, si el ID de esa tabla es autoincremental todos los intentos fallidos harán que se aumente el contador aunque no se inserte nada. Esto podría hacer que haya muchos saltos sobre todo si el código se ejecuta en bucles o cosas por el estilo. Eso no quita que en la tabla se pongan las restricciones debidas, en este caso `UNIQUE` o `PRIMARY KEY` según convenga.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo, pero en unos sistemas que tengo, últimamente lo estoy haciendo así y mis IDs no se autoincrementan, la verdad voy a ver porque es que no se incrementan dejando esos saltos que usted siempre dice, pero de que a mi no me pasa no me pasa y hago el insert así sin más, y si ya existe el correo no se inserta, y no se autoincrementa nada. Pero como le digo, voy a ver que hago y luego le comento...

Comment: @OCHOA para que eso ocurra la tabla debe tener una columna de tipo `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Revisa [este fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yrf6z5K_), observa que el id **`4`** se perdió, porque se intentó insertar el valor `dog` que ya existía en la tabla. Además, ni siquiera el `INSERT IGNORE` sirvió para evitar esa situación.

Comment: @A.Cedano cierto, ya vi que siempre hago una búsqueda del usuario en cuestión antes y si no existe en la DB lo preparo para luego insertarlo. A veces uno olvida sus propias validaciones porque ya las tiene super familiarizadas.